# How to make my app on Heroku stop timing out

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

I made a simple financial app consisting of a React frontend and Node/express backend that I want to deploy to Heroku. Since it's a small app I put everything (server as well as client files) in the root directory of my git repository. Thus the entry files for frontend (index.html), backend (index.js) and the Procfile required by Heroku are all in the root directory.

The server seems to be working fine, since I can successfully make requests from the locally installed frontend. However it appears that the server cannot serve the static files.

This is the log message from heroku:

```
2021-07-29T15:21:00.260957+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=xpensoft.herokuapp.com request_id=2a484f4d-30cf-49b9-920d-14b9e9be28fb fwd="31.151.16.151" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I am serving the static files using this server code:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
}
```

Anyone has any idea what could be causing the timeout?

EDIT:

Apart from the code above, which is supposed to serve up the static files (which is unfortunately doesn't) there is no specific code in the server file handling the '/' endpoint. There is only code for specific named endpoints.

In the React app I am redirecting the user using React Router:

```
<Route exact path='/'>
   <Redirect to='/user' />
</Route>
```

However the React app is never loaded.

Comment: check heroku logs at heroku console or use Heroku CLI Command "heroku logs -t -a herokuAppName". Post here if you couldn't find root cause.

Comment: Also, what exactly is timing out? The deployment or visiting one of your endpoints?

Comment: I edited the post, please see above. The server seems to be working, however the static files aren't served

Answer (score 0):

request timeout error comes when your app takes more than 30 seconds to send a response back to the client.

So there is some issue with your code which handles the '/' route.

if Your static files are facing issues to get served up, it's most probably the issues with .env file. **So manually add the enviorment variables in Heroku Settings > Config Vars**

Comment: Thank you for your answer However I did set up the config vars correctly in Heroku. So this cannot be the cause.

Comment: the static files are in the root of your directory?

Comment: Yes they are in the root directory

Comment: can you provide the code for '/' router in your question

Comment: I edited my question, I hope this is what you mean